# How do I transpose a single row to a column for conversion to JSON in Oracle Database 12.1?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql

The situation is as follows:

I have a single row (from a query). The data from this row has to be sent to a server in JSON format, where each data entry in the JSON file is a combination of

`"{column_name}": "{column_value}"`.

For this particular case, the input is

```
nr | a  | b    |
---|----|------|
1  | 10 | text |
```

and the output should be

```
{
  "a": 10,
  "b": "text"
}
```

How do I dynamically generate the JSON object in PL/SQL, based on an unknown set of columns? Does this require transposing the row? If so, how?

Comment: So you need to be able to take an arbitrary query and format its results as JSON? 12.2 doesn't have any built-in tools for that - you'd need 12.2+. The external [PL/JSON](http://pljson.sourceforge.net/) can be used in earlier version, but if that's overkill for what you're doing you could fall back to dynamic SQL?

Comment: I know the JSON capabilities of 12.2+, but an upgrade at our company is not going to happen in the near future. Colleagues suggested dynamic SQL already, and similar ways already exist in our database, but the methods in them seemed too heavy for a simple conversion of data to JSON. The main reason for asking this question is to find out a much more simple method, perhaps using (UN)PIVOT, or other SQL tricks that I don’t (yet) know that I could not directly find by simply searching online, until upgrading the database.

Comment: You can't (un)pivot an arbitrary query either though, without dropping to dynamic SQL anyway. Or, possibly, using an XML pivot - but then you have the same issue of extracting an unknown number of key/value pairs from the XML. A pivot doesn't seem appropriate - you have a single row, and you want a single JSON result, not multiple new rows? There isn't really a simple conversion of a generic result, at least before 12.2. I suppose you could look at using a Java stored procedure if the conversion is easier there.

Comment: I am pretty new to Oracle Databases and SQL, so please forgive me for mistaking PIVOT for what I thought it was. Unfortunately using Java is also not an option. The query to convert to JSON always results in a single row. Thanks anyways for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

As you're on 12cR1 you can't use the JSON-generating functionality added in 12cR2. There are existing packages available ([PL/JSON](http://pljson.sourceforge.net/)), but if you only have this one task you could potentially roll your own using the dbms_sql package.

As a fairly simple (!) example, and assuming a single row as mentioned in the question, you could do something like:

```
declare
  -- for query text
  l_query varchar2(4000);
  -- for fetching query results
  l_varchar2 varchar2(4000);
  l_number number;
  l_date date;
  l_timestamp timestamp;
  -- for generated JSON string
  l_json varchar2(4000);
  -- for dbms_sql calls
  l_c pls_integer;
  l_col_cnt pls_integer;
  l_desc_t dbms_sql.desc_tab3;
  l_rc pls_integer;
begin
  -- arbitrary query
  l_query := 'select a, b, c from your_table where nr = 1';

  l_c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(l_c, l_query, dbms_sql.native);
  dbms_sql.describe_columns3(c => l_c, col_cnt => l_col_cnt, desc_t => l_desc_t);

  for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
    case l_desc_t(i).col_type
      when 1 then
        dbms_sql.define_column(l_c, i, l_varchar2, 4000);
      when 2 then
        dbms_sql.define_column(l_c, i, l_number);
      when 12 then
        dbms_sql.define_column(l_c, i, l_date);
      when 180 then
        dbms_sql.define_column(l_c, i, l_timestamp);
      -- more types as needed
      else raise_application_error(-20001, 'Unknown data type ' || l_desc_t(i).col_type);
    end case;
  end loop;

  l_rc := dbms_sql.execute(l_c);
  l_rc := dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_c);

  l_json := '{' || chr(10);

  for i in 1..l_col_cnt loop
    -- name
    l_json := l_json || ' "' || l_desc_t(i).col_name || '": ';
    -- value
    case l_desc_t(i).col_type
      when 1 then
        dbms_sql.column_value(l_c, i, l_varchar2);
        l_json := l_json || '"' || l_varchar2 || '"';
      when 2 then
        dbms_sql.column_value(l_c, i, l_number);
        l_json := l_json || l_number;
      when 12 then
        dbms_sql.column_value(l_c, i, l_date);
        l_json := l_json || '"' || to_char(l_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') || '"';
      when 180 then
        dbms_sql.column_value(l_c, i, l_timestamp);
        l_json := l_json || '"' || to_char(l_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3') || '"';
      -- more types as needed
      else raise_application_error(-20001, 'Unknown data type ' || l_desc_t(i).col_type);
    end case;
    if i < l_col_cnt then
      l_json := l_json || ',';
    end if;
    l_json := l_json || chr(10);
  end loop;

  l_json := l_json || '}';

  dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_c);

  -- for debugging, to see generated value
  dbms_output.put_line(l_json);
end;
/
```

You'd probably pass the query into and get the JSON back out of a function or procedure, using a similar mechanism. And you might need a CLOB to hold the generated JSON; and error checks etc...

With a sample table with a date column added for fun:

```
create table your_table (nr, a, b, c) as
select 1, 10, cast('text' as varchar2(30)), sysdate from dual;
```

that gets:

```
{
 "A": 10,
 "B": "text",
 "C": "2019-01-23T07:14:43"
}


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I was searching for a method which excludes the need of declaring each column in creating the JSON, so unfortunately this method isn't 100% what I need. Despite that, the method looks like it would work well and it is definitely worth giving a try. Thanks!

Comment: The columns are only declared in the query itself, the dynamic stuff just uses whatever the query returns. You could use `*` in the query if that was appropriate, though it very rarely is. (If you want lower-case keys then you'll have to either do `lower(l_desct_t(i).col_name)`, or alias the columns with quoted identifiers.)

Comment: I am 100% sure that I want to include every single column into the JSON object, so I'll give it a try. Thanks!